Inclusion of R_E in AC and DC analysis of BJT

we agree that the value of Re exists when analyzing the DC analysis of this circuit, right?
But when we do the AC analysis of this circuit, Re resistance does not exist, because there is a parallelism with the capacitor.
I want to clarify these two pieces of information. Am I right?

AC analysis requires knowing the slope of the BE junction at the operating point, which you don't show or discuss in your question. Also, the emitter capacitor, as shown completely bypassing the emitter resistor, will shift the emitter voltage phase by a full 90 degrees and greatly reduce its amplitude, as well. That's from an AC perspective. DC is just finding the operating point of the circuit and the capacitors can be ignored for that.

Yes, both points are correct, with the caveat that the second is true only to the extent that the reactance of the capacitor is low enough (i.e., the frequency being considered is high enough) to be negligible in the overall analysis.
The "corner" frequency between these two regimes can be calculated from the time constant formed by \$R_E\$ and \$C_E\$: $$f_C = \frac{1}{2 \pi R C}$$ As long as the frequency is much less than \$f_C\$ or much greater than \$f_C\$, then you can apply your rules of thumb.

I see, so can the same issue be mentioned for jfets?

Generalisms: -

At DC, the capacitor is regarded as an open circuit
At AC, the reactance of the capacitor is regarded as dominating the resistance of Re

The above situations are a generalism. Reality dictates that we take the parallel arrangement into account. A good example might be audio where the lowest audio frequency (normally regarded as 20 Hz) will produce a capacitive reactance that is of the same order as Re.

I see, so can the same issue be mentioned for jfets?

@softcalculate this isn't specific to any component. It's just that you can't just say "AC, so any capacitor is a short": it depends on capacity and frequency and what is around and in series of that capacitor. Linear network theory – the very basics!

@softcalculate or MOSFETs or tubes/valves or op-amps or any circuit using a parallel RC network.
